# when i am trying to sort the array its giving an error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
TYPE myarray is varray(10) of pls_integer;
unsorted myarray := myarray();
min pls_integer;
begin
  unsorted := myarray(2,5,8,6,4,9,1,3,7,10);
  FOR i in 1 .. unsorted.count-1 loop
  begin 
   for j in i+1 .. unsorted.count loop
   begin
    if(unsorted(j)<unsorted(i))
    then 
      begin
        min := unsorted(i); 
        unsorted(i) := unsorted(j);
        unsorted(j) := min; 
      end;
     end if;
 end;
 end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line(unsorted(i));
 end;
 end loop;
 end;
```

my code giving an error i am not able to understand why?
ORA-06550: line 16, column 31:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: bubblesort? make your collection a SQL type, and then use select to sort it.

Answer (score 3):

You use `min` as a variable, but `min` is a reserved keyword. Use another variable name instead, and it should be working.